# Retrieving and Analysing data from multiple JTextFields

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener, jtextfield

I am creating a program were the user enters their grade of all their assignment and the weight of each individual assignment and the program calculates the aggregate grade.

Nearly completed the program with loads of help from here/internet but I have no idea how to do this last section.

[image]

So when user clicks enter the program will aggregate all marks taking into account their specific weight and output an average. For example:

[image]

The equation for something like this is weight/100*mark. (Adding them all together). So... (40/100)*60 + (40/100)*80... etc

So how can I do this with my program? I need to implement some type of for loop because the number of assignments changes all the time.

I have already implemented an actionlistener on the Enter button were the Mark/Weight/Assignment counter gets passed on to the next class.

However the actionlistener only records the last mark/weight. so 50 and 20 in the example above. This is another problem I'm facing.

**So basically I ask for a way to get inputs from all JTextField and analyse them to create one output which aggregates all the scores. (Considering their weight)**

Code:

```
public class test{

public JButton button;

private static final Insets normalInsets = new Insets(10,10,0,10);
private static final Insets finalInsets = new Insets(10,10,10,10);

private static JPanel createMainPanel(){
    GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();

    //Adding the JPanels. Panel for instructions
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

    int gridy = 1;

    //JLabel for the Instructions
    JTextArea instructionTextArea = new JTextArea(5, 30);
    instructionTextArea.setEditable(false);
    instructionTextArea.setLineWrap(true);
    instructionTextArea.setWrapStyleWord(true);

    JScrollPane instructionScrollPane = new JScrollPane(instructionTextArea);
    addComponent(panel, instructionScrollPane, 0, gridy++, 3, 1, finalInsets, GridBagConstraints.CENTER, GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL);

    //JLabels for Assignment
    JLabel label1 = new JLabel("Assignment");
    label1.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
    addComponent(panel, label1, 0, gridy, 1, 1, finalInsets,GridBagConstraints.CENTER,GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL);

    //JLabel for Mark
    JLabel label2 = new JLabel("Mark");
    label2.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
    addComponent(panel, label2, 1, gridy, 1, 1, finalInsets, GridBagConstraints.CENTER, GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL);

    //JLabel for Weight.
    JLabel label3 = new JLabel("Weight");
    label3.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
    addComponent(panel, label3, 2, gridy++, 1, 1, finalInsets, GridBagConstraints.CENTER, GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL);

    //JLabel Number for the number list of assignments at the side.
    gbc.gridy = 3;

    for(int i = 1; i<=3; i++){
        String kok = String.valueOf(i);
    JLabel number = new JLabel(kok);
    number.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
    addComponent(panel, number, 0, gbc.gridy++, 1, 1, normalInsets, GridBagConstraints.CENTER, GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL);
    }
    gbc.gridy =3;

    //JTextfield for Mark
    for(int i=0; i<3; i++){
    JTextField mark = new JTextField(20);
    mark.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
    addComponent(panel, mark, 1, gbc.gridy++, 1, 1, normalInsets, GridBagConstraints.CENTER,GridBagConstraints.NONE);
    }
    gbc.gridy = 3;

    //JTextfield for Weight       
    for(int i=0; i<3; i++){    
    JTextField weight = new JTextField(20);
    weight.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);   
    addComponent(panel, weight, 2, gbc.gridy++, 1, 1, normalInsets, GridBagConstraints.CENTER,GridBagConstraints.NONE);
    }

    JButton button = new JButton("Enter");
    button.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    addComponent(panel, button, 3, gbc.gridy++, 1, 1, normalInsets, GridBagConstraints.CENTER,GridBagConstraints.CENTER);

return panel;
}

private static void addComponent(Container container, Component component, int gridx, int gridy, int gridwidth, int gridheight, Insets insets, int anchor, int fill ){
    GridBagConstraints grid = new GridBagConstraints(gridx, gridy, gridwidth, gridheight, 1.0D,1.0D,anchor,fill,insets,0,0);
    container.add(component,grid);
}


    public static void main(String[] args) {    
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.add(createMainPanel());
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
    new test();
}
```

The next class that has the mark/weight info.

```
public class test1 implements ActionListener { 

 private final JTextField mark;
 private final JTextField weight;



public test1(JTextField mark, JTextField weight) {
    this.mark = mark;
    this.weight = weight;

}


@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

String markstring = mark.getText();
String weightstring = weight.getText();

double markdouble = Double.parseDouble(markstring);
double weightdouble = Double.parseDouble(weightstring);  

}
```

Comment: Keep a reference to the text fields in a collection or an array ('unknown number' suggests a collection).  Iterate the collection to calculate the final result.

Comment: Yeah I was thinking of a for loop to fill the array for mark/weight but not sure how to start it off for multiple JTextFields

Comment: .. OK.  What have you researched based on that?  What have you **tried?**

Comment: For example, I tried doing JTextField[] mark = new JTextField(20); . This will not work with my code as I need it to be a straight JTextField for formatting issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You just need to save your `JTextFields` in a vector, so you can access them later.
- You don't need the second class.
- The listener for your button was also created.

  ```
  import java.awt.Component;
  import java.awt.Container;
  import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
  import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
  import java.awt.Insets;
  import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
  import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
  import javax.swing.JButton;
  import javax.swing.JFrame;
  import javax.swing.JLabel;
  import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
  import javax.swing.JPanel;
  import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
  import javax.swing.JTextArea;
  import javax.swing.JTextField;
  import javax.swing.SwingConstants;

  public class Test {
      public JButton button;

      private static final Insets normalInsets = new Insets(10,10,0,10);
      private static final Insets finalInsets = new Insets(10,10,10,10);

      public final static int NUM_OF_FIELDS = 3;

      private static JTextField[] markTextFields = new JTextField[NUM_OF_FIELDS];
      private static JTextField[] weightTextFields = new JTextField[NUM_OF_FIELDS];

      private static JPanel createMainPanel() {
          GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();

          //Adding the JPanels. Panel for instructions
          JPanel panel = new JPanel();
          panel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

          int gridy = 1;

          //JLabel for the Instructions
          JTextArea instructionTextArea = new JTextArea(5, 30);
          instructionTextArea.setEditable(false);
          instructionTextArea.setLineWrap(true);
          instructionTextArea.setWrapStyleWord(true);

          JScrollPane instructionScrollPane = new JScrollPane(instructionTextArea);
          addComponent(panel, instructionScrollPane, 0, gridy++, 3, 1, finalInsets, GridBagConstraints.CENTER, GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL);

          //JLabels for Assignment
          JLabel label1 = new JLabel("Assignment");
          label1.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
          addComponent(panel, label1, 0, gridy, 1, 1, finalInsets,GridBagConstraints.CENTER,GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL);

          //JLabel for Mark
          JLabel label2 = new JLabel("Mark");
          label2.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
          addComponent(panel, label2, 1, gridy, 1, 1, finalInsets, GridBagConstraints.CENTER, GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL);

          //JLabel for Weight.
          JLabel label3 = new JLabel("Weight");
          label3.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
          addComponent(panel, label3, 2, gridy++, 1, 1, finalInsets, GridBagConstraints.CENTER, GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL);

          //JLabel Number for the number list of assignments at the side.
          gbc.gridy = 3;

          for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
              String kok = String.valueOf(i);
              JLabel number = new JLabel(kok);
              number.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
              addComponent(panel, number, 0, gbc.gridy++, 1, 1, normalInsets, GridBagConstraints.CENTER, GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL);
          }
          gbc.gridy = 3;

          //JTextfield for Mark
          for (int i = 0; i < NUM_OF_FIELDS; i++) {
              JTextField mark = new JTextField(20);
              markTextFields[i] = mark;
              mark.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
              addComponent(panel, mark, 1, gbc.gridy++, 1, 1, normalInsets, GridBagConstraints.CENTER, GridBagConstraints.NONE);
          }
          gbc.gridy = 3;

          //JTextfield for Weight       
          for (int i = 0; i < NUM_OF_FIELDS; i++) {    
              JTextField weight = new JTextField(20);
              weightTextFields[i] = weight;
              weight.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);   
              addComponent(panel, weight, 2, gbc.gridy++, 1, 1, normalInsets, GridBagConstraints.CENTER,GridBagConstraints.NONE);
          }

          JButton button = new JButton("Enter");
          button.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
          addComponent(panel, button, 3, gbc.gridy++, 1, 1, normalInsets, GridBagConstraints.CENTER,GridBagConstraints.CENTER);
          button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
              @Override
              public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                  double finalScore = 0;
                  for (int i = 0; i < NUM_OF_FIELDS; i++) {
                      double weight = Double.parseDouble(weightTextFields[i].getText());
                      double mark = Double.parseDouble(markTextFields[i].getText());
                      finalScore += weight / 100 * mark;
                  }
                  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Final score: " + finalScore, "Final Score", JOptionPane.OK_OPTION);
              }
          });
          return panel;
      }

      private static void addComponent(Container container, Component component, int gridx, int gridy, int gridwidth, int gridheight, Insets insets, int anchor, int fill) {
          GridBagConstraints grid = new GridBagConstraints(gridx, gridy, gridwidth, gridheight, 1.0D, 1.0D, anchor, fill, insets, 0, 0);
          container.add(component, grid);
      }

      public static void main(String[] args) {    
          JFrame frame = new JFrame();
          frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
          frame.add(createMainPanel());
          frame.pack();
          frame.setVisible(true);
          new Test();
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: Thanks very much. Was looking into Vectors and this saved me an incredible amount of time. Thanks again.

Comment: `Vector`?  What year are we living in?  Also `static` is NOT your friend and this WILL bite you the rear

Comment: If he's learning why souldn't he start by learning what a vector is? I tryed to grab he's code and make simple changes so things could work the way he wanted. Instead of making those kind of comments why don't you give him a better solution and theach him how to use lists and non static methods/variables? :)